How to auto-adjust height of rows in a table?
I have very simple groff file:
.ps 14
.TS
tab(;) doublebox allbox expand;
rb rb
l ^
l l.
111;222
333
444;555
.TE

with a table which looks as:

As you see only "222" is in the middle of the row. All other cells are located wrongly - too high up. As I understood it happens because I changed type size (.ps 14) and it seems it does not affect the table (its rows). I never used groff before so I supposed it will auto-extend the height of the rows, but it does not happen. How to fix this problem? What is the right way to change type size outside tables?

ouch, only 20 watchers for groff. There is an usenet group hierachy based on  comp.text so I would post a link to those so you get the maximum viewers for your problem. (I don't have the time now to research this) . Good luck.

You can set the vertical spacing of the lines with .vs. In general, you would set the vertical spacing a bit larger than the font size:
.ps 32
.vs 36p
.TS
tab(;) doublebox allbox expand;
rb rb
l ^
l l.
111;222
333
444;555
.TE

gives:

